# TinyMCE keyup enter key to call function in component

Tags: tinymce, angular8

I am using Angular 8 and TinyMCE v5. I have a custom component component that includes the tinymce editor with config properties associated.

`<tinymce #editor [config]="context.config" [(ngModel)]="context.message">`

I also have a button that has a callback function when clicked. As normal, after I type into the text editor, I use the button to call a function which captures the editor content. However, I want to also to allow the same function to be called when the enter key is pressed in the editor based on a condition. How can I accomplish this?

The problem I am running into is that I cannot access the component function from the config properties where I can specify in the setup.

Let me know if I need to include more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Official TinyMCE Angular component, you can bind editor events via a shorthand prop on the editor component, for example:

```
<editor (onKeyUp)="handleEvent($event)"></editor>
```

https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-angular#event-binding

This way, you can bind to the editor event from outside of the editor configuration properties.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. While this could work, I am trying to use the same tinymce directive I have specified in my example. Any idea on how to get this working with that example?